# How to dynamically change figure axis from linear to log?

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to dynamically change the y-axis in a Bokeh figure based on the property a user chooses to plot. The properties the user can choose between can be quite different i scale, hence the need for a way to update the y-axis between linear and log scale would be an advantage.

I have tried to update the `.formatter` and `.ticker` of `yaxis[0]` but observe no change of the scale. What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.models import LogTickFormatter, LogTicker, BasicTickFormatter, BasicTicker
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

data = {'core' : ['A','B','C','D'],
        'porosity': [0.29,0.27,0.31,0.28],
        'bottom' : [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01],
        'permeability' : [70,6000,2000,500]}

src = ColumnDataSource({})


def update_property(attr, old, new):
    src.data = {'core' : data['core'],
                'bottom' : data['bottom'],
                'value': data[new]}

    if new == 'permeability':
        p.yaxis[0].formatter = LogTickFormatter()
        p.yaxis[0].ticker=LogTicker()

    else:
        p.yaxis[0].formatter = BasicTickFormatter()
        p.yaxis[0].ticker=BasicTicker()


p = figure(x_range = data['core'], plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           toolbar_location=None, tools='')

p.vbar(x='core', bottom= 'bottom', top = 'value', width=0.9, source = src)


prop_select = Select(
    title = 'Select property to view',
    options=['porosity', 'permeability'],
)
prop_select.on_change('value', update_property)

layout = row(widgetbox(prop_select), p)

prop_select.value = 'porosity'


curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: This is a dupe of the above answer, and I still don't think it is possible. I don't have much to suggest besides the tab option there, although hiding/showing two plots might also work. I would suggest a GitHub feature request issue for live linear/log axis switching, so that this use-case can be addressed explicitly and put under test.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now its a duplicate. Seems that an issue has already been opened, [6575](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6575)